# Spark-SQL error with external Hive metastore

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

So the company I work for has an in-house metadata system to manage metadata (databases, tables, partitions, etc) that are stored on S3.
They recently added a API layer on top of the system so that it can be used as an external Hive meatastore.

When I start a spark-sql session and point to the service endpoint, I could see all the databases and tables. Then when I query the tables I got following error:

```
spark-sql> select * from insertions limit 1;
2018-10-22 15:20:22 ERROR SparkSQLDriver:91 - Failed in [select * from insertions limit 1]
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.UnresolvedCatalogRelation.<init>(interface.scala:426)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.lookupRelation(SessionCatalog.scala:681)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$lookupTableFromCatalog(Analyzer.scala:662)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.resolveRelation(Analyzer.scala:617)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:647)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:640)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
```

I'm suspecting this is because certain Hive metastore APIs were not implemented.

Anyone has any idea what could be missing here?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d7a35877b96dce8b742acf77e79bda189e402ae2/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/catalog/interface.scala#L426 - `assert(tableMeta.identifier.database.isDefined)`

Comment: Yeah I have seen the code. I don't understand why tableMeta.identifier.database.isDefined returns false. I was able to see the database within spark-sql shell.

Comment: There's a difference between _"seeing the database"_ (as in SHOW DATABASES) and _"retrieving a `Table` object from a Thrift message and checking that it is related to a persistent database"_...

Comment: TL;DR > just report the bug to the team that implemented the Thrift service that tries to emulate a Hive Metastore, and let them sort it out.